# Why are there two different units for charge; the coulomb and elementary charge?

Tags: charge, units, si-units

Why are their two different units for $q$ charges?

Comment: There isn't. The elementary charge is also measured in Coulomb. i.e., Qe=1.6x10^-19 C.

Comment: Don’t forget the statcoulomb…

Answer (score 2):

The elementary charge is a constant, which expresses the charge of one electron in terms of coulombs, but it's not really a unit. You could express a quantity of charge using the *charge number* which is a unitless value that describes how many elementary charges are present.

If your question is why bother with different ways of describing the amount of electric charge, it's the same reason we have the units of meters and light-years, or joules and electronvolts, or pascals and atmospheres - certain values are simply more convenient in certain domains in order to have physically convenient values that may avoid lots of decimal places or extra orders of magnitude.